# Building setup.exe for 64 Bit Operating System

Tags: installshield

I need to create a setup which targets 64 bit O.S.,Currently my project is **Installshield 2008 Premier Edition** and type is **InstallScript MSI** and we right now we are supporting 32-bit O.S.

I have some set of questions

1. Do i need to build Installshield on 64-bit dedicated machine ??
2. Is it possible to have same project which supports 32-bit as well as 64-bit? If Yes how to approach?
3. Is single Setup.exe will support both 32-bit and 64-bit ??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, you can build in either environment, unless you need to do things like 64-bit COM Extraction which must run on a 64-bit platform. However 32-bit packages should be fine building from either environment.
2. It's possible to create a project with multiple product configurations that each target different platforms (different template summaries, possibly different release flags). I'm not sure I'd want to try to do that with an InstallScript MSI project type.
3. InstallShield does not yet create a single installer that really supports both platforms. You can hack it together in an InstallScript project, for the most part, but Windows Installer requires different packages for different platforms, and setup.exe only supports one.

Comment: I never came back to update this; InstallShield 2012 and later offer the Suite (or Suite/Advanced UI) project type which better supports case 3.